# Long running PHP in Fancybox

Tags: php, iframe, fancybox

I got a php script that I am running in an iframe Fancybox window (Fancybox 2)
The PHP script uses flush to output data while running to indicate what is going on..
Script runns for about 1.5 min.

Works great when its running in standalone window.
But in an Iframe Fancybox there is no output until the script is fully loaded, only the loading spinning wheel is shown for the 1.5 min. Then all the info comes out.

Can i somehow get the fancybox window to show the info "live"?

Tnx

Comment: Hmmm .. what is the relevance of the long-integer tag?

Comment: hm.. none.
That word must have been autogenerated. Im deleting it.

Comment: What if you set `iframe: {preload: false}` in fancybox options?

Comment: Thank you @PhilippeBoissonneault
That did the trick! :)
Also found another thread now when I knew what I was looking for..
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14545769/view-contents-of-cart-inside-fancybox-blank-page-only-in-ie8/14552475#14552475]

Answer (score 0):

In fancybox options :

```
iframe: {preload: false}
```